# Angular ui grid error in css file

Tags: angular-ui-grid

When i was try implement angular ui-grid, I am geeting this error. some help me to sort this problem.

[image]

Comment: please give us some more information about this!! Just one error line without any information about the code you use to import, the version of ui-grid-unstable etc, finding the solution is like searching the needle in the haystack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess:

To import css you should use this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ui-grid-unstable.min.css" />
```

in your index.html.

I guess you import it as Javascript which will not work.

Comment: The import as a script came from the website example.  I copied and pasted and ended up with the same problem.